# Swift get array of strings from 2d array

Tags: arrays, swift, string, character, 2d

Here is my code:

```
var parentList = [String]()

for user in MPUser.array {
    if user.childParent == "parent" {
        parentList.append(user.firstName)
    }
}

guard parentList.contains((selectedSecondJob?.assigned)!) else {
    print("payday has to be a parent, yo!")
    return
}
```

It works, but I know I can make it more "Swifty" by using a higher order function like flatMap.

Here's what I tried:

```
let parentListTEST = MPUser.array.flatMap({ $0.childParent })
```

But it returns an array of Characters, not Strings. Why? The MPUser array is an array of structs that clearly defines the "parent" parameter as a String, not Character.

How do I get a new array from my MPUser array that just has the names of the parents as Strings and not Characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try either

```
let parentListTEST = MPUser.array.filter { $0.childParent == "childParent" }.map { $0.firstName }
```

Or

```
let parentListTEST = MPUser.array.compactMap { $0.childParent == "childParent" ?  $0.firstName : nil }
```

Comment: If you `filter` then `map`, you should `.lazy` first, to prevent intermediate array allocations and element copies

Comment: typo `comapctMap`

Answer (score 1):

Use `map`.

`flatMap` flattens nested collections. You're mapping over a list of `User`s, getting an array of `childParent` `String`s (which are themselves collections of `Character`), which `flatMap` is flattening out into a single array.

You just want the mapping without the flattening, so just use `map`.

Comment: using `map` isn't enough op wants to conditionally return according to `$0.childParent == "childParent"` value

Comment: Ah yes, the filtering would be extra. The `compactMap` approach is better.

Comment: @PhontaineJudd can you add how this works ? i mean final code ?

Comment: I was premature in my excitement. It didn't work like I thought.